# React: How to Expand All nodes and Collapse All Nodes in treeview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a treeview control from Xml data. On page load, all the nodes are in collapse mode. I have two links ExpandAll (this will expand all the nodes) and Minimize All link(this will collapse all nodes) . Please find the sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i

Please let me know how to ExpandAll/MinimizeAll nodes using react?

thanks